# How to pass multiple arguments to delete operation on trigger?

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
estado numFactura
a      1
a      2
c      3
c      4
```

---

```
create trigger deleteFactura 
on factura
INSTEAD OF DELETE
as
declare @estado varchar
set @estado= (select estado from deleted);
begin
    if @estado='c'
    THROW 51000, 'La factura esta cerrada, no se puede eliminar', 1
    else
    delete from factura
    where numFactura=(select numFactura from deleted)
end 
go
```

Goal: delete registers with `estado ='c'` and leave the ones with `estado='a'` be

I need it to work with more than one value. 
If I try to delete two values, I get this error:

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Procedure deleteFactura, Line 6 [Batch Start Line 9]
>   Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

How can I make it accept multiple values?

Comment: Your code looks more like SQL Server.  What database are you really using?  Please tag appropriately.

Comment: The error here pretty much reveals everything, the sub-query is returning two rows instead of one so your where clause wont work.

Comment: Yep I know, I just don't know to adapt it, I've searched a lot of solutions

Comment: You need to overcome the idea that you must retrieve and store something in a variable in order to evaluate it. You use trivial logic like "if exists (select * from deleted where estado = 'c' then throw ... else ... end; " And stop the laziness - **ALWAYS** define a length when declaring strings.

Comment: Always use set operations not individual row-by-row operations.

Answer (score 0):

When writing triggers always keep in mind that it may be processing several records. 
The records that are being inserted, deleted, or updated, are available in tables INSERTED and DELETED. i.e. They appear to be tables, but they only exist within your trigger.

```
create table dbo.Invoices ( Status varchar(1), InvoiceNum int )

go

create trigger DeleteInvoice on Invoices
instead of delete
as
delete from Invoices where InvoiceNum in ( select InvoiceNum from deleted ) and Status='a'

go


insert into Invoices ( Status, InvoiceNum ) values
( 'a', 1 ), ('a', 2 ), ('c', 3 ), ('c', 4 )

select * from Invoices

delete from Invoices

select * from Invoices
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to JOIN with the deleted collection to select just the rows you want to delete, and add the appropriate WHERE clause... something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER DeleteInvoice ON Invoices
INSTEAD OF DELETE
AS
BEGIN
    DELETE inv
      FROM Invoices inv 
           INNER JOIN deleted d ON inv.InvoiceNum = d.InvoiceNum
     WHERE inv.Status = 'a'
END
```